# How to fix this gnome clock?

Tags: gnome

In order to show different time zones on my ubuntu desktop (Ubuntu 20.04.4) I installed `gnome clocks`, but after some while this is what I see:

[image]

I really don't need to see my current time zone three times.
When I first started the app it looked on, the current time zone was shown only once. But then after time (like 10 minutes), the current timezone was duplicated. I cannot remove them.

Is there a fix to this problem, or exists a very similar app to just easily show one different time zone?

Comment: You might report this as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-clocks) but given the number (and age) of unassigned, unresolved bugs, I wouldn't count on a quick fix.

Comment: Wow latest bug report from 2017... I guess it is faster to create an app by myself. Maybe I will do; I will then post it as answer ...

Comment: You didn’t sort the big list… The most recent bug report is from [September 2021](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-clocks/+bug/1943815). The last bug fix was in [Dec 2020](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-clocks/+bug/1898411).

Comment: Oh ok. But it still seems outdated. I have created my own app now.

Answer (score 1):

To properly show two timezones in an app you can use python and tkinter. Here is an example where you have to define the timezone in the code:

```
# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# importing strftime function to
# retrieve system's time
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone    

tokyo = timezone("Asia/Tokyo")

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Clock')

# This function is used to
# display time on the label
def time():
    local_str = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    tokyo_time = datetime.now(tokyo)
    tokyo_str = tokyo_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    lbl.config(text = "Local  " + local_str + "\nTokyo  " + tokyo_str)
    lbl.after(1000, time)

# Styling the label widget so that clock
# will look more attractive
lbl = Label(root, font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
            background = 'purple',
            foreground = 'white',
            justify = RIGHT)

# Placing clock at the centre
# of the tkinter window
lbl.pack(anchor = 'center')
time()

mainloop()
```

When you run this short code, you will get a GUI as follows

[image]

Comment: How do I install `tkinter`? `pip3 install tkinter` gives me `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter`.